# Angular 2 - Karma/Jasmine Trailing white space warning

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Im new to using the Karma/Jasmine testing module for Angular 2. During the the test I keep getting a trailing whitespace warning for code referring to the end of the my components/services. Following is the example of the error I am getting. Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong as it looks fine to me?

Console Warning

```
WARNING in ./src/app/shared/nav.service.ts
[14, 45]: trailing whitespace
[15, 4]: trailing whitespace
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class NavService {
  private navAnnouncedSource = new Subject <string>();
  // Observable string streams
  // Return as observale to encapsulate the subject
  navAnnouncedSource$ = this.navAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  currentView: string = null;
  constructor() { }
  // Service message commands
  announceNav(component: string) {
    this.navAnnouncedSource.next(component); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are spaces at the end of line 14 and 15.

Delete them.

Comment: @KaTech you know you can change all this behavior if you want. All of this stuff is configured in the `tslint.js` file. You can decide what you want to care about, and what not to. But for the sake of keeping the project clean, you should just keep the defaults. Maybe not you, but some people nitpick about things like this.

Comment: You can auto lint your javascript with tools like [xo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/xo/blob/master/readme.md), or any js linter and even execute them with things like [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) which simplifies git hooks so you can auto lint when you commit. But that may be out of scope for current question ;)